# jenkins: ERROR: M2_HOME is set to an invalid directory

Tags: maven, jenkins

I use Jenkins to run my tests. Also I use Maven to build tests.
Then I try to run job I get:

```
ERROR: M2_HOME is set to an invalid directory.
M2_HOME = "C:\test\TestProject\.."
Please set the M2_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of the Maven installation

Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I set M2_HOME in System Variables and it is C:\apache-maven-3.1.1.
Job settings in Jenkins are:

Advanced Project Options:
 Use custom workspace
 Directory - C:\test\TestProject\
Source Code Management: 
 None
Build:
 Root POM - pom.xml
 Goals and options  - clean test

How can I fix this? How can I find from where M2_HOME variable is taken?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838908/hudson-error-m2-home-is-set-to-an-invalid-directory

Comment: I tried solution of this post, but it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

I changed the maven instalation in the system configuration of the jenkins .
Define there the MAVEN_HOME and select it in the maven version of yours project configuration. It worked for me.